# difference between Kernel#eval and Binding#eval in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Why does `Binding#eval` call the block, but `Kernel#eval` does not?

```
def bar; binding; end
bi = bar {|x| p(x+1)}

bi.eval "yield 2"       # ==> 3
eval "yield 2", binding # ==> LocalJumpError
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, on fifth line, second argument must be 'bi':

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]

1 def bar; binding; end
2 bi = bar {|x| p(x+1)}
3
4 bi.eval "yield 2"  #==> 3
5 eval "yield 2", bi #==> 3
```

Comment: How did you configure your IRB?as I am seeing you get the line numbers into it.Any help to configure the same? :)

Comment: I didn't configure irb, I just added line numbers in my comment, for greater understanding :)

Comment: Ohhk!! I thought its automatic:)